# Python 3 постепенное вытаскивание из функции map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, map

Как сделать так, чтобы при работе функции map(), я мог бы работать с уже обработанными им данными. В данном случае лишь эскиз кода. А уже с большими данными приходится ждать довольно долго. Как можно реализовать такую схему?

```
def powers(x):
    return x*x

box = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
box_mapped = map(powers, box)
print(?)
```

или конкретно мой случай:

```
def get_kp():
    # some code

box = [1,2,3,...]
with Pool() as p:
    box_mapped = p.map(get_kp, box)
print() # по одному готовому элементу (необязательно print())
```

Comment: Эм, мап вообще-то не вычисляет все сразу, а выдаёт результаты по мере надобности.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужен именно `map`? Может, лучше будет использовать генераторы, если вам необходимо смаппить какие-то значения поочередно, а не все разом? Для первого примера это будет выглядеть `box_mapped = (powers(x) for x in box)`. Генераторы не хранят весь набор объектов, а выдают их поочередно по мере необходимости, соответственно не занимают много памяти и быстры в инициализации.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов в первом коде можно обойтись без map(), но вот во втором случае, где я использую Pool, там, кажется, уже нельзя, но я точно не могу сказать. Вот у меня конкретно случай под Pool

Comment: @PavelDurmanov А каким образом можно вытаскивать данные по мере надобности во втором коде?

Comment: Не понятна логика второго примера. Что за объект `Pool`? Почему он имеет метод `map`? Мне кажется, вы сформулировали неправильную логику работы своей программы и привязались к `map`, который, скорее всего, и не нужен вовсе.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов библиотека, "from multiprocessing import Pool". Создает несколько процессов, по умолчание это кол-во ядер. И получается если у компьютера 8 ядер, то функцию map() будут выполнять параллельно 8 процессов

Comment: Ох, извините, с данным модулем я не работал, думаю, мои комментарии в таком случае можно проигнорировать.

Comment: Хотя нет. Почему бы вам не инициализировать генератор перед распараллеливанием? А затем в процессах дёргать `next(box_mapped)`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов генератор то можно использовать для box, но дергать его лучше через imap. иначе получится очень неоптимизированное ipc c блокировками

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def foo(a):
    print(f'sqrt {a}')
    return a ** 2


data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

mapped = map(foo, data)

for i in mapped:
    print(i)
```

Рзультат:

```
sqrt 1
1
sqrt 2
4
sqrt 3
9
sqrt 4
16
sqrt 5
25
```

Как видим исполнение идёт не сразу, а по мере необходимости.

А теперь с процессами:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        for i in pool.imap(foo, data):
            print(i)
```

Реультат:

```
sqrt 1
sqrt 2
sqrt 3
sqrt 4
sqrt 5
1
4
9
16
25
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь итератором:

```
def powers(x):
    return x*x

box = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
box_mapped = iter(list(map(powers, box)))

print(box_mapped.__next__()) #0
print(box_mapped.__next__()) #1 и т. д.
```

Comment: ээ, а смысл? Вы вычисляете весь мап и только тогда делаете итератор

Comment: @PavelDurmanov А вы прочитайте вопрос. `Как сделать так, чтобы при работе функции map(), я мог бы работать с уже обработанными им данными`

Comment: > А уже с большими данными приходится ждать довольно долго

Comment: мап уже выдает итератор